# How do you create a progress bar in excel VBA without having your steps in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, status

I'm extremely new to VB.  I've managed to put together a form that gives users the option to pick from 10 different checkboxes (all or any combination) that will run a query against our database and bring back the results into an excel worksheet (a separate worksheet for each option).  Basically in my submit button code, the code says If ckboxA = True Then Call query A End If, If ckboxB = True Then Call query B End If, etc...(Each of my queries is a separate Sub in 1 Module - not sure that's important, but just in case).

Some of the queries are really quick while others take some time, I want to provide a progress bar so that the user knows the process is running and gets an idea of progress being made.  I've watched video after video, but they all involve a loop where the same thing is being done over and over so the progress is pretty easily measured.  How do I do this in my situation, can I add something in my "If" statement for each of the options?

Comment: Do you mean VB.net or VBA, because those are not the same?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications

Comment: Just like the windows update progress bar is fake, yours can be too. The user isn't too concerned about the accuracy as knowing that it's going.